# Merge "redundant" sqlite left join rows in a javascript array to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite, join, group-by

I am creating a REST API in expressjs for my website, currently I have a `Product` table like this:

```
id | name 
1  | Shirt
```

Products can have known flaws, listed in a seperate table `Flaw`

```
id | desc          | productId
1  | short sleeve  | 1
2  | no buttons    | 1
```

On my front end, I want to have all flaws listed for that product, so I need a JSON like follows:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Shirt", "flaws": [{"desc": "short sleeve"}, {"desc": "no buttons"}]}]
```

Currently, my SQL query in express looks like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT Product.id, Product.name, Flaw.desc FROM Product LEFT JOIN Flaw ON Flaw.productId = Product.id"
```

and this is how I do the call and get it to JSON:

```
    db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
      if(err){
        res.status(400).json({"error": err.message});
      }
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    });
```

However, this results me in the following:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Shirt", "desc": "short sleeve"}, {"id": 1, "name": "Shirt", "desc": "no buttons"}]
```

I understand that this is due to the nature of my SQL query (using LEFT JOIN), but I'd like to know a good way of "merging" the redundant parts into one item (id, name) and have a "sub pair" called flaws in my JSON, where the non redundant flaw parts are listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your json directly from a query:

```
SELECT json_object(
         'id', p.id, 
         'name', p.name,
         'flaws', json_group_array(json_object('desc', f.desc))
       ) result 
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN Flaw f
ON f.productId = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=034b1db8ce2abce4cb33b3697f71d42d).

Comment: Works perfectly for my case! What if you'd have a second join that you'd want to combine, [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3ad0a349ab19e258da59e61275c52445)? I know in this case one table (e.g. Feedback) with a isFlaw flag might be smarter, but for the sake of the demo I added a benefit table, whos value is printed twice (as theres two flaws) when doing it in the above way

Comment: @OneFD in this case you should aggregate inside Flaws and Benefits and do LEFT joins of Products to the resultsets: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a491ce99c0fe69878ad9d13e86d23a81